# What is the probability that if you toss a coin until the first head appears it takes exactly 5 tosses

Tags: probability

[image]

If anyone can look at my two approaches so far and let me know which makes more sense. Whether 1/32 or 5/9 and/ or what adjustments need to be made to either approach. Thank you!

Comment: The answer is $\frac{1}{32}$.  I do not see how you came to an answer of $\frac{5}{9}$ but the fact that the denominator is not a power of two should be a major red flag that it isn't correct for a question about fair coin sequences that isn't a conditional probability question.

Comment: The answer si $1/32$ if the probability of heads is the same as the probability of tails which is nowhere written in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I see how you get $\frac 59$, but there seem to be two problems for this method. First, you seem to be counting as successes sequences in which the first head appears before the fifth throw, and this is contrary to the problem statement. Second, you seem to be assuming that the nine possibilities you have listed are all equally probable, and this is not the case either.

There is just one sequence of five throws which counts as a success, namely TTTTH. All sequences of five are equally probable, and there are $32$ of them.

If you want to analyse in the alternative way, then the failures are

After one throw H with probability $\frac 12$

After two throws TH with probability $\frac 14$

After three throws TTH with probability $\frac 18$

After four throws TTTH with probability $\frac 1{16}$

After five throws TTTTT with probability $\frac 1{32}$

Answer (score 0):

No head before the 5th throw, hence you only want one sequence $TTTTH$, therefore the second results which is $\frac{1}{32}$